# TITAN : Identify and remove duplicate vertices in graph

Tags: graph, graph-databases, titan, gremlin

I am using TITAN 0.4 over Cassandra, I have indexed my key ("ip_address" in my case), but as NON-UNIQUE, for performance and scalability.
Now the challenge is graph allows duplicates vertices.
I am running a background task to cleanup the duplicate vertices in graph, by iterating through all vertices. 
What is the best way or approach to identify a duplicate vertex in a graph.
The the estimated size of graph in production is around 10M ~ 15M vertices or even more than that.
Is there any feature exist in TITAN index, which helps to easily identify a duplicate? 
Thanks in advance

Index creation Gremlin script

```
g.makeKey("ip_address").dataType(String.class).indexed("standard",Vertex.class).make();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start with a Titan/Hadoop job:

```
g.V().ip_address.groupCount()
```

Then use those IP addresses with a count > 1 to clean up / merge duplicated vertices in OLTP mode.